# Diagnosing dead soldering-iron

Tags: soldering, triac, repair, thyristor, diagnostics

My soldering iron was working fine for a few years. One day, I used it and it worked fine again, then I unplugged it then tried to use it again a couple of hours later but it wouldn't heat up.

I took it apart and pulled a Big Clive and mapped out the schematics. I tested the few components and they seem fine. Both of the SMD resistors check out as does the SMD capacitor. The diode doesn't register with the diode-tester on my DMM, but my Mega328 ESR/LCR tester detected it as a diode. I don't know what resistance the pot should have, but it definitely seems to have a range (it's not shorted or open).

The 97A6 thyristor/triac seemed dead (I don't recall the exact nature of the failure), so I got a pack of MAC97A8s, tested one, and put it in. I don't *think* the orientation of the triac should matter, the gate is in the center either way and iirc, the anodes are both functionally equivalent.

The only thing left that could have a problem is the ceramic heating element, but I have no idea how to test that (I don't know what properties, such as resistance, it's supposed to have).

Is there some way to diagnose the problem?

I already got a replacement, but I'd like to salvage this iron and avoid throwing it out if possible. (My old one with the wire-wound element died the same day this one died, so I'd like to keep this as a backup until I can get another backup backup, and also just not waste what seems like a perfectly usable iron—well, other than the not working. )

---

Front (with new triac):
[image: Dead Soldering Iron Front]
Back (with wires splayed to show traces—yes, I know I didn't trim the leads yet):
[image: Dead Soldering Iron Back]
Original triac:
[image]

Comment: Triacs are *not* symmetrical. MT1 \$\ne\$ MT2

Comment: Doh. Well I checked the photo I took of the original before putting the replacement in, and it was flat-face-down. I checked the datasheets for the original and the replacement and they both had the same pinouts, so it (should be) correct. (I also tried putting a triac in the other way around as a test, but that didn't work either.)

Comment: The soldering on pretty much all components is poor. D1 in particular looks very fishy. I would strongly advise to redo every single joint, use flux. Very ironic that the companies making solder irons don't know how to do proper soldering...

Comment: You can usually find an inexpensive heating element on Bang Good or where else these soldering irons are sold. Try Amazon too.

Answer (score 2):

Element is often a prime contender.
Resistance when hot is about
R = V _squared/Power_max.
R is usually reasonably temperature independent.

R MAY be lower if they never run at 100 % duty cycle.

Place a resistor of somewhat above R_calculated across element, set on low heat and see if it gets warm.